# Creating Windows Registry SubKey .NET Core 8 using Domain Admin Acct throws Denied Access exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, registry, .net-8.0

I've been troubleshooting some code I inherited from another developer who is no longer with the company, see below, and have run out of ideas on what could be the problem. Could use some extra eyes looking at this to see what I may have missed.

The code has been running for more than a year until it was migrated to a new host in a different AD domain. The new host like the old is an AD joined 2016 Server and the Windows accounts I've used for testing were a local admin account and a domain admin account. I have gotten the same error messages using both accounts. The only other difference that comes to mind is that the code was running under .NET Core 6 on the old host and now on the new host, it is running under .NET Core 8. I haven't read anything about changes in .NET Core 8 that would impact using the Microsoft.Win32 library.

This application processes the log files from a mail server and writes them to a SQL database, so this is its only function, consequently the UAC settings have been turned off. The code is trying to create a registry sub key under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node`.

This is a simplified version of that code:

```
public class TestCase
{
    private const string MYAPPROOTKEY = "SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\MyApp";

    public TestCase()
    {
        // Current Windows Acct is a member of Domain Administrators and
        // it is a member of the local Administrator's Group
        WindowsIdentity _WindowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        RegistryKey _HKLM = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine;
        RegistryKey _MyAppKey = OpenSubKey(_HKLM, MYAPPROOTKEY);

        if (_MyAppKey is null)
        {
           RegistrySecurity _RegistrySecurity = CreateElevatedRegistryRule(_WindowsIdentity);
           _HKLM.SetAccessControl(_RegistrySecurity);
           // throws Exception: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

           RegistryKey _MyAppRootKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(MYAPPROOTKEY, 
           RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryOptions.None);

           // Throws exception: Access to the registry key
           // 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\MyApp'
           // is denied.
       }
    }

    private static RegistryKey OpenSubKey(RegistryKey p_RegistryKey, string p_SubKey)
    {
        RegistryKey _RegistryKey = null;

        try
        {
            _RegistryKey = p_RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(p_SubKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree,
            RegistryRights.ReadKey
            | RegistryRights.EnumerateSubKeys
            | RegistryRights.QueryValues
            | RegistryRights.ReadPermissions);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            string _Msg = ex.Message;
            System.Exception _ApplicationException = FormatExceptionMsg.PrepareApplicationException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex);
            DebugLogger.Write(LogEventLevel.Error, _ApplicationException, _Msg);
            SerilogConsoleLogger.Write(LogEventLevel.Error, _Msg);
        }

        return _RegistryKey;
    }

    private static RegistrySecurity CreateElevatedRegistryRule(WindowsIdentity p_WindowsIdentity)
    {
        RegistrySecurity _RegistrySecurity = null;

        try
        {
            _RegistrySecurity = new RegistrySecurity();
            _RegistrySecurity.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(
                p_WindowsIdentity.Owner,
                RegistryRights.ReadKey
                | RegistryRights.WriteKey
                | RegistryRights.ReadPermissions
                | RegistryRights.SetValue
                | RegistryRights.CreateSubKey
                | RegistryRights.Delete
                | RegistryRights.EnumerateSubKeys
                | RegistryRights.QueryValues,
                InheritanceFlags.None,
                PropagationFlags.None,
                AccessControlType.Allow));
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            string _Msg = ex.Message;
            System.Exception _ApplicationException = FormatExceptionMsg.PrepareApplicationException(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex);
            DebugLogger.Write(LogEventLevel.Error, _ApplicationException, _Msg);
            SerilogConsoleLogger.Write(LogEventLevel.Error, _Msg);
        }

        return _RegistrySecurity;
    }
}
```

Everything else the code does under these admin accounts works just fine, so I started looking at whether or not the User Account Control settings may be the problem. Even though I set UAC to their lowest value, that has not solved the problem. But in examining the registry keys for UAC, there are several settings I’m not familiar with. I’m hoping someone can clarify whether or not these could be the problem.

The registry setting for UAC can be found at: `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System`

The settings and values I'm unfamiliar with, that may be the source of this exception are:

```
FilterAdministratorToken = 0
EnableUIADesktopToggle = 0
ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin = 0
ConsentPromptBehaviorUser = 3
EnableLUA = 1
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by taking apart the original developers code and simplifying it, proving once again that more often than not, less is more:

```
    //RegistrySecurity _RegistrySecurity = CreateElevatedRegistryRule(_WindowsIdentity);
    //_HKLM.SetAccessControl(_RegistrySecurity);
    // threw Exception: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

    //RegistryKey _MyAppRootKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(MYAPPROOTKEY, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryOptions.None);
    // Threw Access Denied exception,
    // This code worked just fine.
    RegistryKey _MyAppRootKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(MYAPPROOTKEY);
```